# What does %0x%x mean in C/C++ programming?

Tags: c, memory, buffer

I have the following code, but I'm not sure what `%0x%x` means in the following code?

```
sprintf(buf, "pixel : %0x%x \n", gpbImageData[100]);
OutputDebugString(buf);
```

`gpbImageData[100]` is pointing to an image data in the memory.

Comment: If the argument really is a pointer, you should be using `%p`.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ and then if you have more questions, just ask.

Comment: +1 @OliCharlesworth.  However, from the name of that variable I'm betting that `gpbImageData` is the pointer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth only if you want to print the numerical representation of the pointer itself. I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: Yeah - I think the OP is being a bit misleading saying `gpbImageData[100]` is a pointer.  I guess I don't know the context, but the format string and variable name hint that it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You certainly meant this format string `"0x%x"`

```
sprintf(buf, "pixel : 0x%x \n", gpbImageData[100]);
```

This adds the `0x` prefix to the hexadecimal numbers when they are written in `buf`.

Note that you can achieve the same thing with the flag character `#`:

```
sprintf(buf, "pixel : %#x \n", gpbImageData[100]);
```

Answer (score 12):

Your example causes undefined behaviour.  The format string will cause `sprint` to expect two `int` values:

```
%0x
%x
```

Both of these mean exactly the same thing - print a value as a hexadecimal number.  However, the call you've shown passes only one argument.

Are you sure it doesn't say `0x%x`?  If it doesn't, it's probably supposed to... that would be more normal, and will print the passed-in value as a hexadecimal number prefixed with `0x`.

Your code as shown should cause a warning.  `clang` gives:

```
example.c:5:15: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
  printf("%0x%x\n", 125987);
             ~^
1 warning generated.
```

and `gcc` says:

```
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:5: warning: too few arguments for format
example.c:5: warning: too few arguments for format
```

Both without providing any flags at all.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format is "0x%x" as ouah and Carl Norum said. Whatever gpbImageData[100] content (pointer or number), %x will print its value as a hexadecimal number. 0x is just a text. Maybe "gpbImageData" is an array of pointers.